# Is there anyway of shortening this ternary statement in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$loc = (isset($this->news_options[$this->reference]['generate']))
? $this->news_options[$this->reference]['generate'] : array();
```

Put it on 2 lines so it's easier to read. So basically is there any way of referencing the initial array key that is checked after the question mark? I can't store it as a variable as 
as I will get an error if the key isn't set.

So is there any other way of doing something like the following in PHP?

```
$loc = (isset($this->news_options[$this->reference]['generate'])) ? <-assign that to loc : array();
```

I may be missing something completely obvious but I can't seem to figure it out!

Comment: You can make a generic function to do this, and whenever you need it, just call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another ternary statement with `isset()` to assign the key value to a variable, like so:

```
$generate = (isset($this->news_options[$this->reference]['generate']) ?
$this->news_options[$this->reference]['generate'] : NULL ;
```

Now you can do:

```
$loc = (isset($generate))
? $this->news_options[$this->reference]['generate'] : array();
```

If the variable you want to assign is the same as the `$generate` variable, then simply replace `$this->news_options[$this->reference]['generate']` in the second ternary statement with `$generate`.

Answer (score 0):

Wow sorry, figured this out right after posting. I just needed to assign the part of the array that I knew would definitely be there to a variable first.

```
$part1 = $this->news_options[$this->reference];

$loc = (isset($part1['generate'])) ? $part1['generate'] : array();
```

Comment: (which is basically what [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19874628/1438393) suggests :P